# Having trouble unsetting session variable in Yii2

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2, unset

I'm using `Yii2` and I have just started working with `sessions` within it. I have read the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html) for them on the Yii site.

One thing I noticed is it is a bit hard to work with multi-dimensional arrays in sessions without using the standard superglobal `$_SESSION` and hence I have mainly been using that.

One thing I am having trouble doing though is unsetting a session variable.

Example:

```
if (!Yii::$app->session->isActive) {
    Yii::$app->session->open();
}

print_r($_SESSION['foo']);

if ($this->command == 'sample_action') {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['foo'][$this->some_id][$this->example_id])) {
        $_SESSION['foo'][$this->some_id][$this->example_id] = $this->example_id;
        $result = true;
    }

} elseif ($this->command == 'sample_action_2') {

    if (isset($_SESSION['foo'][$this->some_id][$this->example_id])) {
        unset($_SESSION['foo'][$this->some_id][$this->example_id]);
        //$_SESSION['foo'][$this->some_id][$this->example_id] = ''; // This works
        $result = true;
    }           

}

print_r($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Using `unset` on it doesn't work at all, it still remains. Setting it to a blank value works however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a working solution, hopefully this helps someone else:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;

$foo = $session['foo'];

if ($this->command == 'sample_action') {
    $foo[$this->some_id][$this->example_id] = $this->example_id;
} elseif ($this->command == 'sample_action_2') {
    unset($foo[$this->some_id][$this->example_id]);
}

$session['foo'] = $foo;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->remove('foo');
```

May help you..

Comment: Yes I know you can do that, but how do you remove a value in a `multi-dimensional` array? That will only remove `$_SESSION['foo']` as a whole.

Comment: Try `foreach ($session as $name => $value) { $session->remove('$value); }`

Comment: That is not going to work either; `remove` only has the capability to remove at the first level.